# How many disks for Windows Raid 0?

Tags: windows-8, software-raid

I am setting up a new PC and have 3 identical disks.  Does it make sense to stripe all three or is two sufficient?  I don't really need extra space, so wondering if 3 will yield better performance than two.

Comment: Raid 0 is inherently unsafe. I'd consider using Raid 5 with all 3 disks. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels

Comment: Just be careful with RAID5 - if two disks go then you'll lose the lot. Multiple backups is crucial in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

Every disk in RAID-0 increases read/write performance **and** chance of failure - even if one disk dies, whole system dies.
So I'd recommend to either:

- add another disk and set up RAID-10
- set up RAID-0 with two disks and backup important data to third disk
- set up RAID-5 as Tetsujin advised, however RAID-5 has lower performance